# Terraform stuck on `Refreshing state...` when running against `localstack`

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, localstack

I am using `Terraform` to publish lambda to AWS. It works fine when I deploy to AWS but stuck on "Refreshing state..." when running against `localstack`.

Below is my `.tf` config file as you can see I configured the lambda endpoint to be `http://localhost:4567`.

```
provider "aws" {
  profile    = "default"
  region     = "ap-southeast-2"

  endpoints {
      lambda = "http://localhost:4567"
  }
}

variable "runtime" {
  default = "python3.6"
}

data "archive_file" "zipit" {
    type        = "zip"
    source_dir  = "crawler/dist"
    output_path = "crawler/dist/deploy.zip"
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename      = "crawler/dist/deploy.zip"
  function_name = "quote-crawler"
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::773592622512:role/LambdaRole"
  handler       = "handler.handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.zipit.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime = "${var.runtime}"

}
```

Below is docker compose file for `localstack`:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4567-4583:4567-4583"
      - '8055:8080'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES-lambda }
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-docker-reuse }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 20):

This is how i fixed similar issue :

- Set `export TF_LOG=TRACE` which is the most verbose logging.
- Run `terraform plan ....`
- In the log, I got the root cause of the issue and it was :

```
dag/walk: vertex "module.kubernetes_apps.provider.helmfile (close)" is waiting for "module.kubernetes_apps.helmfile_release_set.metrics_server"
```

- From logs, I identify the **state** which is the cause of the issue: `module.kubernetes_apps.helmfile_release_set.metrics_server`.
- I deleted its state :

```sh
terraform state rm module.kubernetes_apps.helmfile_release_set.metrics_server
```

- Now run `terraform plan` again should fix the issue.

This is not the best solution, [that's why I contacted the owner of this provider to fix the issue without this workaround](https://github.com/mumoshu/terraform-provider-helmfile/issues/21).

Answer (score 3):

The reason I failed because `terraform` tries to check credentials against AWS. Add below two lines in your .tf configuration file solves the issue.

```
skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
```

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same issue and fixed it by logging into the aws dev profile from the console.
So don't forget to log in.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-2"
  profile = "dev"
}
```